# Apple Watch for Workouts Without Phone

Tags: apple-watch

In short, I'd like to be able to complete a workout without having to bring my phone along. The introduction of native apps for the Apple Watch seemed like it would open the door to this, but I've not been able to figure it out. I would need:

- Heart Rate Monitoring
- An Interval Timer
- Music via BT Headphones

Can the Apple Watch do this? If not, any alternate suggestions?

Comment: I'm developer of [Periodic Timer app for iPhone and Apple Watch](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/periodic-timer/id933241656) which some people use as interval timer. And I can say about some problem that all interval timers face. watchOS apps can work when watch is inactive only if it starts a workout AND only one could be started. So you can't user workout app, such as heart rate monitor simultaneously with interval timer. One possible solution is to find a workout app which has built-in interval timer.

Comment: @kelin That is super-helpful context. I appreciate you sharing that.

Answer (score 1):

The current Apple Watch does all that you've asked about.

However, I would recommend waiting until WWDC this June to see what new Watches will be made and what the new costs will be.

Comment: The Apple Watch does do all that, but regarding a 2nd-Generation coming out, I can almost guarantee WWDC is not where the successor will be announced for 2 reasons: 1. WWDC is all about software announcements. I'm certain that we'll see iOS 10 (iOS X??), OS X 10.12, watchOS 3, and likely a new version of tvOS, but I don't think we'll see any new hardware. 2. WWDC is all about developers, not consumers and the press like their other events (not to say non-developer Apple fans won't watch it and the press won't be all over this).

Comment: Apple has made many hardware announcements at WWDC such as the Mac Pro, iPhones 3G, 3GS and 4. Who knows what will be announced but my advice still stands for the OP.

Comment: The Apple Watch has an interval timer? I know it has a stopwatch, but I have to manually manage that time myself, right? I want to set something like three minutes of exercise with a thirty second rest in between for six rounds and have the watch alert me (beep or buzz) at the end of each round. I've seen many apps for the watch that do this, but they all require the phone.

Answer (score -1):

There is an interesting article about it: http://www.macworld.com/article/3069462/ios/how-the-smart-connector-could-be-key-to-an-iphone-pro.html
However I use my AW with iPhone, because one of the most useful apps for it is to control iPhone battery: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/watchmybattery/id1024068907

Comment: While its good to post a link to an answer, you should also include a short summary in your post to truly make for a good answer.

Comment: Did you accidentally post this to the wrong question? This doesn't seem to have anything to do with this one.